# CSS 100% div height with 960 grid

Tags: css, 960.gs

I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out this problem and I have looked high and low for the answer and came up with similar results.

### Synopsis

The problem is that I am building a website using the 960 grid and have three columns that I want to stretch at 100% at all times.  Here is a fiddle for your reference: http://jsfiddle.net/Uec7h/1/

Essentially the html is like so:

```
<div class="contentWrapper">
    <div class="container_12">

        <div class="grid_2 leftSide clearfix">
            Left sidebar content.
        </div>

        <div class="grid_7 content">
           Lots of content loaded from the server.
        </div>

        <div class="grid_3 rightSide">
            Right sidebar content.
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

with the CSS being like

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
}

.leftSide {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.rightSide {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.contentWrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
```

The fiddle isn't completely accurate to what I am seeing on my local version, but it's close.  Seems like the left and right sidebars do not want to expand to 100% no matter what I do.

### What I've Tried

Most of the answers I have found on SO have suggested to put `height: 100%` on the `html, body` elements and everything should work out fine.  Adding this attribute and giving both sidebars `height: 100%` did work a little bit, but if the content in the middle column gets too big, it stops at a certain point and won't continue to stretch.

I have tried adding the `clearfix` class that comes with the 960 grid but it didn't seem to help at all.

### Question

How do I get the left and right side bars height in the fiddle to be 100% no matter what content is in the middle column?

Comment: You want to give the black blocks height 100% ? sry iam not good in English ...

Comment: Essentially.  I am trying to make those sidebars expand to the height of the browser no matter what it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following CSS to the sidebar elements it will fill the 100% of the height.

```
display:block;
height:auto;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
```

If you place the sidebar into a wrapper `div` with `relative` positioning, the content section will be again in it's right place...

I would also set `padding` and `margin` to 0 for the body.

**EDIT:**

If you add `height: 100%` to the `.container_12` it will get a real height, and children elements can have a 100% height. Notice that the sidebars will be as height as the window itself, but your content at the middle can be taller than 100%... [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uec7h/3/)

Comment: This isn't working for me.  Would you mind updating the fiddle with your answer?  I would like to try and keep the `relative` position but also stretch to 100%.  I am not sure how you're structuring here.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know the 960 grid, the EDITED solution - using visibility: visible; -

HTML

```
<div id="box">  
    <div class="vision"> sdfsdfsd </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#box  { 
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid red;

}
.vision {
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    visibility: visible; 
}
```

Comment: posted an edit - came to think of the visibility-thing when returning to the question

Comment: However - might not be crossbrowser as far as i remember -